# How to interpret $R^2$ above 1?

Tags: modeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R^2, ESS, TSS - how well my model predicts outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/r2-ess-tss-how-well-my-model-predicts-outcome)

I have already posted [longer version of my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/r2-ess-tss-how-well-my-model-predicts-outcome), however I have obtained no answer, so I will try to make it simpler.

I have calculated ESS and TSS for many cycles and my R^2 values where from 0.99 to 1.05. How can I interpret this? Do I have an error in my calculations? I am operating on values within range from 0 to 1 if it matters.
The exact way of how I calculate ESS and TSS and what I am working on is available in the question, to which I have already given [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/r2-ess-tss-how-well-my-model-predicts-outcome) at the beginning.
Of course I do not believe that my model is so good - what I am afraid that I use inapriopriate way of verifying how well my model reflects real values.